# Data from DB is in browser console log but not in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

My previous question was about not being able to fetch data from DB but now I can see fetched data in console log. The **new** problem is that this data is not being displayed on my HTML page. Someone asked me about OPTIONS headers before my first request but in console I only see GET headers for the fonts. [image]

browse.component.html

```
<div><ul style="list-style-type: none; color: whitesmoke;">
         <li>OS</li>
      <li *ngFor="let item of Categories; let i = index ">
           <a>{{item.NAME_OS}}</a>
         </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

browse.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Category} from '../shared/category';
import {TovarService} from '../shared/tovar.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-browse',
 templateUrl: './browse.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./browse.component.css']
})
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {
 Categories: Category[];
 constructor(private tovarservice: TovarService) {
   this.Categories = [];
 }

 ngOnInit(){
   this.Categories = this.tovarservice.getCategory();
 }

}
```

category.ts

```
export class Category{
 NUM_OS: number;
 NAME_OS: string;
 constructor(NUM_OS: number, NAME_OS: string) {
   this.NUM_OS = NUM_OS;
   this.NAME_OS = NAME_OS;
 }
}
```

category.php

```
<?
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token, content-type');
include('connection.php');
$result3=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT NUM_OS, NAME_OS from OS") or die("can't retrieve");
if($result3){
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
 $obj1 = array();
 for($i =0; $i <$rows; $i++){
   $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);
   $obj1[$i]["NUM_OS"] = $row[0];
   $obj1[$i]["NAME_OS"] = $row[1];
     }
 echo json_encode($obj1);
 mysqli_free_result($result3);

}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Category } from './category';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {Product} from './product';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
 getCategory(){
   return this.http.get('http://localhost/category.php').pipe(
     map(resp => resp),
     catchError((error: any) => throwError(error)));
 }
}
```

tovar.service.ts

```
import {Category} from './category';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from './http.service';
import {Product} from './product';

@Injectable()
export class TovarService{
 Categories: Category[];

 constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
   this.Categories = [];
 }
 getCategory = (): Category[] => {
   this.httpService.getCategory().subscribe((resp => {
     console.log('inside category', resp); return resp;
       for (let index in resp){
         let cat1: Category = new Category(resp[index].NUM_OS, resp[index].NAME_OS);
         this.Categories.push(cat1);
       }
     }));
   return this.Categories;
 }
}
```

Comment: You're returning right after the console.log, so your code never enters the for loop to push into `this.Categories`

Comment: Check what inside `this.Categories` instead of `resp`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the variables to uppercase because fields of the Category table were in uppercase. Everythig works now

Answer (score 0):

`httpService.getCategory()` fills `Categories` inside an inner subscription. When your component's `ngOnInit` is running, the service level `this.Categories` is empty.

I don't see a real point on keeping `Categories` in both service and component. The simplest solution would be to replace this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of Categories; let i = index ">
     <a>{{item.NAME_OS}}</a>
</li>
```

With (After changing the access modifier of `tovarService` to `public`):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of tovarService.Categories; let i = index ">
     <a>{{item.NAME_OS}}</a>
</li>
```

However, I'd probably remove the array-related logic from the service and return the `Observable` itself from the service, then handle the array in the component.